# Whey from yogurt to curdle milk

Tags: cheese, cultured-food, whey

I know that adding acid to milk being cooked, will yield curdles that one can strain and store as cheese.

Is it possible to use the whey from my homemade yogurt (now greek-style yogurt), but instead of cooking everything in a pot, I let it sit in proofing temp for a few hours? Will I get the same result, while preserving the cultures?

The milk used for the yogurt was not cooked. The yogurt was subsequently strained over coffee filters. So I have as much whey as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you let the whey sit with the milk at proofing tempreatures (about 42 to 49 C for lactobacillicus bulgaricus, somewhat lower for bifidus, streptococcus delbrueckii and some other strains), you'll get yogurt again.

In order to get your type of "curds" (corresponding to Russian tvorog, or German quark, or Indian paneer), you need to use acid and heat together. The yogurt whey is a good source of acid, yes. But you definitely have to follow the process as it is, including the heating.

Comment: why not I split a carton of milk in two, to experiment both ways.

Comment: The reason to not experiment is food safety. If you hold your mixture of whey and milk at 45-ish C, then there is no need to do that experiment, it's a traditional way of making yogurt. But if you hold it for several hours at 50 or above, you will fail to get yogurt, instead getting other, dangerous kinds of bacteria to colonize your milk. Boiling is yet another matter, it will kill both the yogurt culture and the other bacteria types. So don't experiment at temperatures between yogurt-making ones and tvorog-making ones.